# Extended computation expressions without for..in..do

Tags: f#, dsl, computation-expression, query-expressions

*What I mean by extended computation expressions is computation expressions with custom keywords defined via [CustomOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh289709.aspx) attribute.*

When reading about [extended computation expressions](http://files.meetup.com/2922732/Computation%20Expressions%20%28April%29.pdf), I come across very cool IL DSL by @kvb:

```
let il = ILBuilder()

// will return 42 when called
// val fortyTwoFn : (unit -> int)
let fortyTwoFn = 
    il {
        ldc_i4 6
        ldc_i4_0
        ldc_i4 7
        add
        mul
        ret
    }
```

I wonder how the operations compose without using `for..in..do` construct. My gut feeling is that it starts with `x.Zero` member, but I haven't found any reference to verify that.

If the example above is too technical, here is a similar DSL where components of a slide are listed without `for..in..do`:

```
page {
      title "Happy New Year F# community"
      item "May F# continue to shine as it did in 2012"
      code @"…"
      button (…)
} |> SlideShow.show
```

I have a few closely related questions:

- *How does one define or use extended computation expressions without `For` member (i.e. provide a small complete example)?* I don't worry much if they aren't monads any longer, I'm interested in them in developing DSLs.
- *Can we use extended computation expressions with `let!` and `return!`? If yes, is there any reason of not doing so?* I ask these questions because I haven't encountered any example using `let!` and `return!`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm glad you liked the IL example.  The best way to understand how expressions are desugared is probably to look at the [spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818835) (though it's a bit dense...).

There we can see that something like

```
C {
    op1
    op2
}
```

gets desugared as follows:

```
T([<CustomOperator>]op1; [<CustomOperator>]op2, [], fun v -> v, true) ⇒
CL([<CustomOperator>]op1; [<CustomOperator>]op2, [], C.Yield(), false) ⇒
CL([<CustomOperator>]op2, [], 〚 [<CustomOperator>]op1, C.Yield() |][], false) ⇒
CL([<CustomOperator>]op2, [], C.Op1(C.Yield()), false) ⇒
〚 [<CustomOperator>]op2, C.Op1(C.Yield()) 〛[] ⇒
C.Op2(C.Op1(C.Yield()))
```

As to why `Yield()` is used rather than `Zero`, it's because if there were variables in scope (e.g. because you used some `lets`, or were in a for loop, etc.), then you would get `Yield (v1,v2,...)` but `Zero` clearly can't be used this way.  Note that this means adding a superfluous `let x = 1` into Tomas's `lr` example will fail to compile, because `Yield` will be called with an argument of type `int` rather than `unit`.

There's another trick which can help understand the compiled form of computation expressions, which is to (ab)use the auto-quotation support for computation expressions in F# 3.  Just define a do-nothing `Quote` member and make `Run` just return its argument:

```
member __.Quote() = ()
member __.Run(q) = q
```

Now your computation expression will evaluate to the quotation of its desugared form.  This can be pretty handy when debugging things.

Comment: Actually I was waiting for your answer. Do you have your IL DSL document or publish anywhere? It would be a very good example to gain understanding and inspiration. The trick with `Quote` member will be helpful too. Thanks.

Comment: @pad - No, it's not currently published anywhere - it's really just a very simple proof of concept with a lot of limitations.  I'll try to clean it up a bit and get it out in some form in the near future.

Comment: @pad - it's now published at https://github.com/kbattocchi/ILBuilder.  Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this `Quote` trick a little bit.  I'm sure it's easy but I can't find any docs on it and it is not obvious to me how to employ it.

Comment: @uosɐſ On your computation builder, add `Quote` and `Run` members as in my answer.  Then whenever you evaluate your computation expression (e.g. `myBuilder { myOp1; myOp2 }`) the result will be an `Expr<_>` containing the set of calls that the compiler would have made if you hadn't added the `Quote` method.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 9):

I have to admit I do not fully understand how computation expressions work when you use *query expression* features like the `CustomOperation` attribute. But here are some remarks from some my experiments that might help....

Firstly, I think it is not possible to freely combine standard computation expression features (`return!` etc.) with custom operations. Some combinations are apparently allowed, but not all. For example, if I define custom operation `left` and `return!` then I can only use the custom operation *before* `return!`:

```
// Does not compile              // Compiles and works
moves { return! lr               moves { left 
        left }                           return! lr }
```

As for the computations that use only custom operations, most common cusotom operations (`orderBy`, `reverse` and this kind) have a type `M<'T> -> M<'T>` where `M<'T>` is some (possibly generic) type that represent the thing we're building (e.g. a list).

For example, if we want to build a value that represents a sequence of left/right moves, we can use the following `Commands` type:

```
type Command = Left | Right 
type Commands = Commands of Command list
```

Custom operations like `left` and `right` can then transform `Commands` into `Commands` and append the new step to the end of the list. Something like:

```
type MovesBuilder() =
  [<CustomOperation("left")>]
  member x.Left(Commands c) = Commands(c @ [Left])
  [<CustomOperation("right")>]
  member x.Right(Commands c) = Commands(c @ [Right])
```

Note this is different from `yield` which returns just a single operation - or command - and so `yield` needs `Combine` to combine multiple individual steps if you use custom operations, then you never need to combine anything because the custom operations gradually build the `Commands` value as a whole. It only needs some initial *empty* `Commands` value that is used at the beginning...

Now, I would expect to see `Zero` there, but it actually calls `Yield` with unit as an argument, so you need:

```
member x.Yield( () ) = 
  Commands[]
```

I'm not sure why this is the case, but `Zero` is quite often defined as `Yield ()`, so perhaps the goal is to use the default definition (but as I said, I'd also expect to use `Zero` here...)

I think combining custom operations with computation expressions makes sense. While I have strong opinions on how standard *computation expressions* should be used, I do not really have any good intuition about computations with custom operations - I think the community still needs to figure this out :-). But for example, you can extend the above computation like this:

```
member x.Bind(Commands c1, f) = 
  let (Commands c2) = f () in Commands(c1 @ c2)
member x.For(c, f) = x.Bind(c, f)
member x.Return(a) = x.Yield(a)
```

(At some point, the translation will start requiring `For` and `Return`, but here they can be defined just like `Bind` and `Yield` - and I do not fully understand when is which alternative used).

Then you can write something like:

```
let moves = MovesBuilder()

let lr = 
  moves { left
          right }    
let res =
  moves { left
          do! lr
          left 
          do! lr }
```

Comment: Thanks Tomas. Your answer cleared up a few doubts. As much as I like this feature, it remains mysterious to me. The lack of documentation (or even semantics) is the main problem.